# addActionListener cannot be added to given type?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ServiceBrowser{
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JComboBox serviceList;
    ServiceServer server;

    public void buildGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RMI Browser");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);

        Object[] services = getServiceList();
        //rmi registry lookup, get stub, call getServiceList

        serviceList = new JComboBox(services);
        //add services(array of objects) to Jcombobox,
        //knows how to make displayable strings out of 
        //each thing in array

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, serviceList);
        serviceList.addActionListener(new MyListListener());

        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }//end buildGUI

    void loadService(Object serviceSelection){
        try{
            Service svc = server.getService(serviceSelection);
            mainPanel.removeAll();
            mainPanel.add(svc.getGuiPanel());
            mainPanel.validate();
            mainPanel.repaint();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }//add actual service to gui after user selects one
        //(this method called by event listener on combobox)
        //call getService() on remote server(stub), pass it
        //same string in the list, server returns actual service(serialized)
        //and call getGuiPanel on service and add result (jpanel) to browser mainpanel
    }

    Object[] getServiceList(){
        Object obj = null;
        Object[] services = null;
        try{
            obj = Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/ServiceServer");
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        server = (ServiceServer) obj;
        //cast the stub to remote interface so we can call getServiceList on it

        try{
            services = server.getServiceList();

        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

    class MyListListener implements ActionListneer{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            Object selection = serviceList.getSelectedItem();
            loadService(selection);
            //user made selection from jcombobox list, take selection
            //load appropriate service
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ServiceBrowser().buildGUI();
    }
}
```

error:

```
row 25: addactionlistener in class JComboBox<e> cannot be applied to given type 
    serviceList.addActionListener(new MyListListener());
ServiceBrowser.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations
```

I know this means that there is a collection somewhere that doesn't declare its type, but I am not sure what is the issue. I think it has something to do with serviceList taking an array of objects? JComboBox constructor says it takes a list of objects, so I am not sure the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small typo:

```
class MyListListener implements ActionListeneer {
                                            ^
```

should be

```
class MyListListener implements ActionListener {
```

Comment: I had to re-read your answer a couple times before seeing it. 1+

Comment: thanks all my errors are gone except "uses unsafe or unchecked operations". Any idea what is the solution

Comment: You need to parameterize your `JComboBox` declaration/implementation, e.g. `JComboBox<?> serviceList = new JComboBox<>(services);`